# Can't access Logitech C930e (webcam) under Ubuntu with SimpleCV

Tags: webcam, logitech

Ubuntu won't recognize my new Logitech C930e webcam fully. Guvcview does (see below). Logitech says it supports UVC 1.5.

I found:
http://sourceforge.net/p/linux-uvc/mailman/message/31645720/

Why isn't it integrated in Ubuntu 14.04 (cheese app)?

I need this camera for [SimpleCV](http://www.simplecv.org/) (which won't recognize it as well).

I figured out:

```
cam = Camera(0)  // -> for the internal notebook (edge 130) webcam
cam = Camera(1)  // -> for the Logitech C930e
```

I receive following errors:

```
SimpleCV:1> cam = Camera(1)
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
```

and with an openCV command:

```
SimpleCV:2>  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl S_FMT
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l1: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl VIDIOCSPICT
```

Comment: Did you installed guvcview?

Comment: Yes, it's installed. Guvcview recognizes the cam, but ubuntu and simplecv not.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Installing common Web Cam driver packages in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Comment: I receive errors: "E: Paket ov51x-jpeg kann nicht gefunden werden.
E: Paket ov51x kann nicht gefunden werden."

Comment: Seems this stuff is already there: "build-essential ist schon die neueste Version.
build-essential wurde als manuell installiert festgelegt.
linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic ist schon die neueste Version.
linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic wurde als manuell installiert festgelegt.
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 22 nicht aktualisiert."

Comment: It says it is already the newest version. Linux-headers was declared as manually installed. 0 acutalized. 0 new installed. 0 to delete and 22 not acutalized.

Comment: I can switch to it over settings. But as soon as I set anything else then 320x240 it says: "Error while processing signal".

Comment: The logitech C930e records 1080p.

Comment: Can you get 1080 with guvcview?

Comment: @Duminud Mahawela Yes I do. 1920x1080 mjpg. I have to select it under the video header first, as guvcview starts up with the internal notebook-cam.